# Nginx reverse proxy to private aws s3 bucket bad gateaway

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-s3, configuration, proxy

I have created a private bucket on aws and I want to reverse proxy it using nginx.
I have used the same server for all the different proxies. 
this is the configuration file for nginx:

```
user nginx;
worker_processes 1;

error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    server_names_hash_bucket_size  64;
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name ec2-...-...-....eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com;  

        rewrite ^(.*) https://$host$1 permanent;
}
server {

    listen 443;
    server_name ec2-...-...-....eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com;  

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;

    ssl on;
    ssl_session_cache builtin:1000 shared:SSL:10m;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    access_log            /var/log/nginx/ssl_access.log;

    location ^~ / {
        #proxy_set_header x-real-IP $remote_addr;
        #proxy_set_header x-forwarded-for $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        #proxy_set_header host $host;
        #proxy_pass https://url.com;  

        #proxy_set_header        Host $host;
            #proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            #proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            #proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

            # Fix the “It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken" error.
            proxy_pass          https://url.com;
            proxy_read_timeout  30;

        proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
        proxy_ssl_verify off;
    }

        location /one/service {

        # proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        # proxy_set_header Host $host;
        # proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
         proxy_pass http://beanstalk-4.212314.eu-central-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/;
         proxy_read_timeout  30;
         proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
         proxy_ssl_verify off;

        }
        location   /privateproxy  {
              set $s3_bucket        'bucketname.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com';
              set $aws_access_key   'AWSAccessKeyId=mykey';
              set $url_expires      'Expires=$arg_e';
              set $url_signature    'Signature=$arg_st';
              set $url_full         '$1?$aws_access_key&$url_expires&$url_signature';

              proxy_http_version     1.1;
              proxy_set_header       Host $s3_bucket;
              proxy_set_header       Authorization '';
              proxy_hide_header      x-amz-id-2;
              proxy_hide_header      x-amz-request-id;
              proxy_hide_header      Set-Cookie;
              proxy_ignore_headers   "Set-Cookie";
              proxy_buffering        off;
              proxy_intercept_errors on;

              resolver               172.16.0.23 valid=300s;
              resolver_timeout       10s;

              proxy_pass             http://$s3_bucket/$url_full;  
        }           
}

  }
```

But I am getting 502 Bad Gateway
Have I done something wrong in the config?

The log file:
2016/03/21 09:13:42 [error] 16695#0: *8 bucket.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com could not be resolved (110: Operation timed out)

Comment: Show the full Nginx config in order to find another (longer) matched location because AWS returns 2xx or 4xx responses, 5xx looks like your custom application, not AWS. Nginx logs are also require for further analysis.

Comment: Thank you @Anatoly. I edited my question.

Answer (score 4):

If bucket name is correct the problem is with resolver. Described IP address: 172.16.0.23 works as DNS server for *non-VPC EC2 only.* If you use VPC, resolver should be equal to want you get from:

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf
```

For example 10.0.1.0/16 VPC subnet may have 10.0.1.2 allocated as internal resolver. If you don't know which one is used (VPC/non-VPC) then open DNS should help:

```
resolver 8.8.8.8;
```

Make also sure you specified plausible S3 bucket name:

```
set $s3_bucket        '-->>bucketname.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com';
```

Comment: Yes! That was the issue with the 502 Bad Gateway. Thank you! It has another problem now though.:Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>
Query-string authentication requires the Signature, Expires and AWSAccessKeyId parameters
</Message>

Comment: @Yianna sure! Please share your S3 URL example first. We also need to know ACL/permissions for particular file.

Comment: The bucket is supposed to be unaccessible from the outside word. I have checked that the url is correct and I found out that my problem is now the signature version 4, since mz instance runs in Franfurt and I am getting "The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256."

Comment: @Yianna how did you generate pre signed URL for S3 content? Do you use up to dated SDK for your platform?

Comment: I tried using aws java sdk to generate the pre-singed url, but I figured out that this needs to be done for every requested item in the bucket seperately, therefore I just used the bucket policy to allow access to a specific ip and keep it private for everyone else. This way no signature is needed. I would still prefer to find a solution for the nginx configuration and signature calculation but this is my workaround to the problem.

Comment: @Yianna to avoid signing each private S3 URL you need to have such Nginx module, which I don't have anything to recommend, we just sign every URL before use, AWS SDK does it job pretty good and fast without making any external calls.

Answer (score 0):

If the EC2 server where you run nginx is in the same VPC as your private S3 bucket
then you can set up an S3 VPC endpoint and update your bucket
policy to use that endpoint ([details here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-private-connection-no-authentication/)), then just add this to your
nginx.conf:

```
    location   /privateproxy/  {
          proxy_pass https://bucketname.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider referencing [this project](https://github.com/nginxinc/nginx-s3-gateway/) from NGINX. It contains all of the configuration needed to proxy a private S3 bucket.